# How do I join one entity to a second entity through a third entity in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I want to give C a reference to an instance of A, but all A has is a foreign key to an instance of B. B has a foreign key to an instance of C. Below is an example.

```
@Entity
public Class A {

  public int id;
  public Integer bId;

}

@Entity
  public Class B {
  public Integer id;
  public Integer cId;
}


@Entity
  public Class C {
  public A a;
  public Integer id;
}
```

How do I use Hibernate annotations in Spring to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think minimal implementation would look like this (using JPA 2.x):

```
@Entity
class A {
    public Integer id;
    public Integer bId;
}

@Entity
class B {
    public Integer id;
    public Integer cId;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="bId")
    private Set<A> a;
}

@Entity
class C {

    public Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    public A a;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="cId")
    private Set<B> b;

}
```

Or if you want to rely on entity references instead of id's:

```
@Entity
class A {
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    public B b;
}

@Entity
class B {
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    public C c;
}

@Entity
class C {
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    public A a;
}
```